# AngularJs Directive help not inserting

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I was wondering whether someone could explain to me how AngularJs directives work.

I have the following code at the moment:

Index.html:

[image]

and my Login.html:

[image]

and finally my login.ts:

[image]

I'm trying to get that template file to be inserted into the index.html file. At the moment it currently just shows a blank screen, rather than the login.html, however when I remove the directive and copy and paste the code into the index.html it is fine and displays perfectly.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: check your console to see what error it is giving you, or paste this code somewhere so we can test it. It's a waste of effort to try and debug your code based on images.

Comment: Hi vileRaisin, there are no error messages in the console.

Comment: check your network tab, is it loading login.html?

Comment: Hi vileRaisin, no it is not.

Comment: I will create a fiddler maybe?

Comment: you named your directive wrong, last line in your ts file

Comment: the html is so called kebab-case, hyphens in kebabcase translate to capital  letters, like camelCase:
`my-directive-for-real-people` -> `myDirectiveForRealPeople`:

Answer (score 2):

you named your directive `loginDirective`, but in your html you use it as `<log-in/>` which is the equivalent of `logIn`, not `loginDirective`

```
.directive('logIn', app.loginDirective);
```

Comment: Yep. Thanks for that. Didn't know about the kebabcase.

Answer (score 0):

```
###################################################################################
# The problem is in your Login.html ... Refer to solution 1 or 2 below
# Both with work. Just ensure that your directive name matches the 
# element 'E' you are injecting in your template.
###################################################################################


//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Solution 1
# login.ts
.directive('loginDirective', app.LoginDirective);


# Login.html
<div>
    <login-directive></login-directive>
</div>


//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Solution 2
# login.ts
.directive('logIn', app.LoginDirective);

# Login.html
<div>
    <log-in></log-in>
</div>

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```